# Read already allocated memory / vector in Thrust

Tags: cuda, wolfram-mathematica, thrust

I am loading a simple variable to the GPU memory using Mathematica:

```
mem = CUDAMemoryLoad[{1, 2, 3}]
```

And get the following result:

```
CUDAMemory["<135826556>", "Integer32"]
```

Now, with this data in the GPU memory I want to access it from a separate .cu program (outside of Mathematica), using Thrust.

Is there any way to do this? If so, can someone please explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this. CUDA contexts are private, and there is no way in the standard APIs for a process to access memory which is allocated in another processes context.

During the CUDA 4 release cycle, a new API called cudaIpc was released. This allows two processes with CUDA contexts running on the same host to export and exchange handles to GPU memory allocations. The API is only supported on Linux hosts running with unified addressing support. To the best of my knowledge Mathematica doesn't currently support this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer talonmies. I know that in C++ however it is possible to read memory locations by manually setting a pointer such as char*e=(char*)0x28fe45. As Thrust uses pointers and Mathematica gives me the memory offet (on the GPU), <135826556> I was thinking that maybe I could manually point to it. Also as I know the var type I should be able to know where the allocation ends as well. Does this seem possible?

Comment: As I already said in my answer, No. There is memory protection in the driver which keeps each context private. The GPU addresses in each context are also virtual, it requires context specific translation lookaside buffer programming to map them to real addresses. The only way this can be done is via cudaipc and Mathematica doesn't support it.